# Implementing Linkedin Autofill Plugin in Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, autofill, linkedin-plugins

Linkedin Tech Solutions direct me here for help.

I am trying to implement Linkedin's Autofill Plugin on https://www.perxtech.com/customer-loyalty-solution-2/ & linkedin ask me to created from scratch on another page https://www.perxtech.com/customer-loyalty-solution-3/.

Both pages failed, as in the autofill button doesn't load, it seems to generate an iframe and then it stopped.

The website runs on wordpress. The form is created using Gravity Forms.

The following is the script I used on the [1st page](https://www.perxtech.com/customer-loyalty-solution-2/) in a HTML placeholder in Gravity Forms itself:

```
<script src='https://www.linkedin.com/autofill/js/autofill.js' type='text/javascript' async></script><script type='IN/Form2' data-form='gform_37' data-field-firstname='input_37_5' data-field-phone='input_37_4' data-field-email='input_37_2' data-field-company='input_37_6'></script>
```

The following is the script I used on the [2nd page](https://www.perxtech.com/customer-loyalty-solution-3/) on the page's code editor:

```
<script src='https://www.linkedin.com/autofill/js/autofill.js' type='text/javascript' async></script><script type='IN/Form2' data-form='gform_36' data-field-firstname='input_36_5' data-field-phone='input_36_4' data-field-email='input_36_2' data-field-company='input_36_6'></script>
```

Linkedin Representatives reassured me that www.perxtech.com has been whitelisted. As quoted from linkedin "*we don’t have to include the full URL, only the high-level domain which will allow you to track any subdomains*"

Both generated the similar error.
[Screenshot of console error taken from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OehTk.png)
Error from Chrome: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

[Screenshot of console error taken from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOe3V.png)
Error from Firefox: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.linkedin.com/autofill/track/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I have tried everything the Linkedin representatives has advised and none of it helps. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You can follow these instructions.  You need to whitelist your domain. https://www.linkedin.com/help/lms/answer/65688/linkedin-autofill-setup-guide?lang=en